# Fix window positioning tooltip by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to fix the window positioning tooltip with page that doesn't out from page (dynamic fix for top right left bottom). I tried the following code but it doesn't work. how should I fix it?

(check if the tooltip height plus the offset height is more than the window height or ?)

**DEMO - full code: [in here see how]** http://jsfiddle.net/xuvAu/1/

```
var tt_ht = $tooltip.height();
p_top = (p_top + tt_ht > $('window').height()) ? p_top - tt_ht : p_top;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
p_top = (p_top + tt_ht > $(window).height() - p_top) ? p_top - tt_ht : p_top;
```

seems to solve your problem :)

Comment: And see this, still don't work true: http://jsfiddle.net/xuvAu/4/ from top and right is out page?

Comment: I won't do your job, please think with your own brain, it's only mathematics here... Moreover, accept the response as it solve the problem of your question.

Comment: You see in above my question it is about (dynamic fix for top right left bottom).
 i  won't do accept your answer because you do not  full answer of my question.

Comment: And I won't. From my answer, you can easily understand how to do it on your own. This website is not a place for delegating his work...

Comment: No, it not, but this is a problem from my code. i want help for solve this problem. i know you are wrong in understand this site and help with delegating work.